# Accessing Google Adwords API from C#.NET windows service

Tags: oauth, google-ads-api

I am creating a C#.NET windows service to create adwords. I understand that I need to use OAuth2 authentication. Do I have to use the services account set up for achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

No. Just install the client library from Nuget.

You can then add your credentials to the app.config file (installing via NuGet creates a template for these credentials in your app.config for you)